# how to save command result output to a file in lua

Tags: lua

The lua script executes the command:
core.console('lf em 410x read')

### As a result, the screen shows:

Read TAG ID:
[+] EM 410x ID B9519AD890

---

How to save the entire screen to a txt file?

This is the response to the command:

EM 410x ID B9519AD890 --- this is to be written to the log.txt file

core.console('lf em 410x read') is an internal proxmark3 command, invoking the command gives the output on the screen.

Solution for my problem?

Comment: How do you execute `proxmark3` (and how does it execute the script containing the call to `core.console`)?

Comment: Looking at the source of proxmark3, this is going to be a tricky one. Calling core.console from Lua makes the rest of the calls on the C side, I can't see any simple way of customising it